# How to edit a value from a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

My data grid has in itemsSource a list of Groups:

```
public class Group : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public Group() { }
    public Group(int groupID, string groupName)
    {
        this.GroupID = groupID;
        this.GroupName = groupName;
    }

    private int _groupID;
    public int GroupID
    {
        get { return _groupID; }
        set
        {
            _groupID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupID");
        }
    }

    private string _groupName;
    public string GroupName
    {
        get { return _groupName; }
        set
        {
            _groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

But I realize that when I edit a cell, I need to press Enter key to fired OnPropertyChanged from Group class. So if I only edit the cell value don't fire the event unless I press Enter key.

Is possible when I edit the cell value without press Enter key, get fired the event?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the default two-way binding to be UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged".

Example from MSDN:

```
<TextBox Name="itemNameTextBox"
         Text="{Binding Path=ItemName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

UpdateSourceTrigger Binding Property Page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UpdateSourcetrigger within your xaml

There are three different kinds:

1. PropertyChanged – The source is updated whenever the target property value
     changes.
2. LostFocus – The source is updated when target property changes and target object looses focus.
3. Explicit – The source is updated when explicit call is made to update using “BindingExpression.UpdateSource”.

Answer (score 0):

> By default the WPF DataGrid will commit a row when focus is lost on the row, the ‘Enter’ key is pressed, tabbing to the next row, or programmatically calling commit on the row.

some more information you get [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/18/wpf-datagrid-sample-locking-input-to-the-row-being-edited.aspx)